# Is there anything special I need to do to use C code in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, g++

Note:  I am using g++ version 4.3.4 to compile my C++ code.

So far, whenever I've wanted to use C style language elements in my code it seems that I can just include the C stuff mixed in and alongside my C++.

I know C++ is *mostly* backwards compatible with C...  so I guess my questions are these:

What parts of C are not forwards compatible with C++?

Will professional programmers laugh at me if I continue to naively stick C stuff into my C++ code?

What is the proper way to have C and C++ code in the same .cpp file?

Can I continue to use g++ to compile my hybrid code?

For this question, I am mostly concerned with a solution that deals with a single .cpp file and a single g++ command to compile it.  I don't really care about linking stuff at this point.

Comment: Backwards compatibility is not really an issue for you, but "forward" compatibility of C to C++ is or am I mixing things up?

Comment: I think the syntactic differences are only the small part of the issue -- C and C++ are different languages, and the way you think and express yourself in them is very different. People won't laugh at you because of syntax, but because of the way you design your programs if you write in a C and C++ "hybrid" style.

Comment: @pmr: At this point, it's really "sideways" compatibility, as there are plenty of C features missing in C++ these days: flexible array members, VLAs, "restrict", designated initializers.

Comment: @pmr:  You got it.  I was just curious about the backwards compatibility part.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Is that sarcasm?  I always wished that sarcasm had a specific font, so all us autistic guys out there would always get it ;)  anyway, tried to tighten up the question for what exactly I am after...

Comment: @Jimmy: I think it's better described as sardonicism.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Great, now we need a whole 'nother font...  the ironing is delicious.

Comment: Good C++ isn't really even close to good C. Besides, C++ has exceptions, which really foobars C code. C++ simply isn't C, mixing them is something that ought to be done carefully and minimally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking out a couple of questions:

"What is the proper way to have C and C++ code in the same .cpp file?"
"Can I continue to use g++ to compile my hybrid code?"

If you want to mix C-style C++ in the same file as regular C++, just go ahead and do it. You can trust the compiler to pick up any issues - they will be minimal and not affect the structure. By the sound of it, you are not interested in getting C-linkage for its own sake, so even if the C-Code is in its own file, compile it as C++. As a matter of fact this is often done as a way of migrating from C to C++.

If you take this approach, your code is not truly hybrid C/C++. It is C++ with some of the code using C-style procedural idioms. C++ is fully intended to support this.

"Will professional programmers laugh at me if I continue to naively stick C stuff into my C++ code?"

It depends where you are using it and why. Well structured C code is good code. Sometimes C+ is *much* better than C at particular problems. Think hard before using C-style dynamic memory management. You will deserved to be laughed at if you use raw `malloc()/free()` and get it wrong.

I suggest that if you embark on this approach, you might later take the time to look back and consider whether or not you would have been better to use C++ idioms instread of procedural C.

Comment: +1 for `You will deserved to be laughed at if you use raw malloc()/free() and get it wrong`. It is difficult and unwieldy to write exception safe code without the use of destructors (RAII), and it is almost never worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

A big gotcha with linking C and C++ code is that the C++ compiler needs to *know* that it is linking against functions that use the C calling conventions instead of the C++ calling conventions. To that end, you often have to wrap your C header files in something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... C function declarations here ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

For lots of details, see the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Answer (score 2):

C++ is almost a superset of C. Therefore, pretty much any feature you can use in C is valid in C++ (but not the other way around).

People might laugh at you for coding some stuff like you would in C, but ignore them. I don't think it's naive, but that may make me naive. I can't tell.

There is no [real] way to seperate C and C++ code in the same file. It just goes with each other, because when you compile it as C++, it's not C any more. So "C alongside C++" is not really the way to think about it.

The only <strike>difference between</strike> thing in C that would keep code from compiling as C++ that I am aware of (besides C++ having more keywords) is the issue with `void*`s. In C, they will implicitly cast to any pointer type, but in C++, you have to have an explicit cast to cast them to another pointer type. There might be others, but I don't know them.

Oh, also, C++ doesn't support "default int". I don't know if it's still valid C these days, but if you leave off the type of a variable or the return type of a function, the compiler would just use `int`. C++ doesn't do that.

Comment: @littleadv yeah that was an horrible way to say it. I meant to say the things that C++ changed to make C not compile. Updated my answer.

Comment: I won't laugh, but I will point out good C code tends to be ugly C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

Most good C practices make for fine compiling C++. A couple of extra pointer casts and renamed identifiers will make for legal C++.

In style, however, C-style code is considered to be horrendous C++. The fact that you *can* write C-style code in C++ should be used if and only if you can't afford to write it in C++ to begin with- i.e., if it's legacy code.

> Will professional programmers laugh at me if I continue to naively
>   stick C stuff into my C++ code?

Basically, yes. C-style coding is known in C++ as "horrendously unsafe", just to begin with. That kind of code is written only by people who don't genuinely know how to use C++. By that, I don't mean doing very low-level stuff like bit twiddling or binary re-interpretation, but things like pointer casting or manual resource management, and that *will* get you laughed at.

Comment: Long story short, I have an algorithm that I am optimizing.  At first, I utilized the STL heavily, and it was slow as a snail.  Largely because I wanted to use <algorithms> without thinking very hard...  but speed is very important, I should really write my own custom algorithms, and in trying to get it up to speed, I'm going down that char[] road pretty hard...  so that's why I'm interested.

Comment: @Jimmy: The algorithm's in `<algorithm>` have always been fast for me. How exactly did you determine it was "slow as a snail? Slowness usually comes from picking the *incorrect* algorithm, not from wrapping the algorithm into a simple-to-use function.

Comment: @Jimmy - You can go down the low-level char[] road while still coding in C++ style. The important thing is to use objects for resource management, and to deeply understand the C++ standard library so that you know how you can do better than it for your particular case.

Comment: @Jimmy: You need to crack out a profiler and actually understand the source. You won't get it any faster by doing an equivalent algorithm mallocing char* than using `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

This is too broad a question; you should break it up into several. There's a way to link together C and C++ object files; C++ is backward compatible with C, and you can use C++ compiler to compile C code.

But, consider this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int class = 0;
    int private = 1;
    return private-class;
}
```

It's valid C code, and obviously won't compile on any C++ compiler if compiled as C++ code. Just an example.

Comment: It's an example, but it's a rather dumb one. It's easy to change variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious key difference is that C++ is object-oriented by design and C is not. That said, you shouldn't have any horrific show-stopping issues compiling C code with g++ unless you run into one of the nasty gotchas that are floating around. You can find a lot of good references for them, and I admit that my answer is far from exhaustive.

It's true that you cannot implicitly cast from `void*` in C++; it won't compile, whereas you'll see it fairly often in C.

You also have to explicitly declare functions in C++ before you use them, where you don't necessarily have to in C. (It's good form to do so, but not all C programmers do.)

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html Now that I'm out of things off the top of my head, this is a good little reference; I use it frequently.